# Finding Duplicates in a CSV using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a couple of CSVs that are over 1GB and will not open in Excel.
There are 5 fields for each row.  I need to compare 3 of these fields (name, size, modified date) and **keep all but 1** of the duplicates. And delete the unique fields as well.

If that isn't possible, then I need to **move all but 1** of the duplicates into another file (the file will then be used to determine which files I need to delete)

Comment: Not a whole lot so far.  I keep finding -unique (which won't work in this case... or would it using a sort...?) and code to keep the current date (but most of my dates are duplicates)

Answer (score 2):

Create a hash table. Read the file row-by-row. Catenate the relevant fields as a key. Check if the key exists in the hash table. If it does, you got a duplicate row. If it doesn't, you got (first occurence of) unique a row. Add it to the hash table and record the row to another a file.